# Cloud Code - include column with user pointer does not work

Tags: parse-platform

I have a table which has a user pointer column with column name "user". In Cloud Code, I want to query that table and include the user objects in the result. From documentation and forums it seems that this should work:

```
var TableWithUserPointer = Parse.Object.extend("TableWithUserPointer");
var query = new Parse.Query(TableWithUserPointer);
query.include("user");
query.find({
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
...
```

But this does not work. Calling results[i].get("user") will return undefined. For some reason which does not make sense to me, using

```
query.include(Parse.User);
```

instead of query.include("user") will return a user pointer in the results but the object only contains the user "id"; no other fields of the user object are populated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! My alternative is gathering all the user pointers and then doing a Parse.User query to get the fully populated user objects, which seems a bit wasteful.

[Parse table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQg4Y.png)

Comment: Can you screenshot the parse web interface for the class and link it?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the Parse class

Comment: @salami your approach seems reasonable.  Just to double check, for the rows in this query, is the user pointer non-empty?  The screenshot shows rows that have the user column being non-empty, but just to be sure, the specific rows you are expecting to have user pointers actually have user pointers in them.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I checked through all the rows and they all have a user pointer like as in the screenshot.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I'm getting something similar. JSON.stringify(user) displays the correct fields in the console, but I can't do user.get("myField").

Comment: I did not. I ended up doing the alternative mentioned at the bottom of my post. Since Parse is shutting down though I'm not longer pursuing this.

Comment: If you can see the fields when you print out in the console though, I wonder if this is a different issue.

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue as @elprl. An array of pointers to users returns objects, not parseObjects. So the data is pretty much there, but can't do user.get('...').
And strangely, it actually works fine at first for me. But the minute I attempt to edit the array on the data browser, it breaks even if I make no changes.

Comment: @ajuser, I can't remember what I did to fix my issue. I think it was to do with an old buggy version of the Parse js SDK. Make sure you deploy to the latest version.